# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions on Testing Library but not App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I am running a Create React App that uses `useDispatch` to dispatch redux actions, `redux-thunk` for async network requests & React Testing Library.

On my app, running localhost, the following works fine, but in test/RTL (`npm run test`) it fails with the `Actions Must Be Plain Objects` error.

```
// CONTAINER

function MyContainer() {
  const [localData, setLocalData] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data, error } = useSelector((state) => state.stocks);

  const fetchStuff = async () => {
    dispatch(fetchMyDataThunk(process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) fetchStuff();
    setLocalData(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div data-testid="test-accts-container">
      <div className={styles.stockListContainer}>
        <p>list of accounts</p>
        <AccountsList passDataInHere={localData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// THUNK

export const fetchMyDataThunk = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loadMyData());
  return Api.fetchStocks(token)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(loadedMyData(res));
      return foo;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(loadMyDataFail(err));
      return bar;
    });
};

// ACTIONS CALLED BY THUNK

export function loadMyData() {
  return {
    type: constants.LOAD_MY_DATA,
  };
}
export function loadedStocksData(data) {
  return {
    type: constants.LOADED_MY_DATA,
    data,
  };
}
export function loadStocksFailed(error) {
  return {
    type: constants.LOAD_MY_DATA_FAIL,
    error,
  };
}
```

The thunk is returning functions that return objects. I'm not sure what I've done wrong?

Comment: are you using a different store in your tests that might maybe missing the thunk middleware?

Comment: @phry good shout, hold i'll check...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @phry - the reason it was erroring with that was the absence of middleware in the test utils store / provider.

Complete oversight on my part. Should've clicked when i was setting up a new store for RTL.

added in thunk middleware.

```
store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk)),
```